How to check NFC availability in flutter?
await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();

Above code of nfc_manager package returns false even if the NFC is available but not enabled. So, Is there any way to check availibility of NFC hardware. Also, any way to openSettings navigating to NFC settings? like location settings.

add Permission for Android like this in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

for IOS:
Add Near Field Communication Tag Reader Session Formats Entitlements to your entitlements.
Add NFCReaderUsageDescription to your Info.plist.
Add com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes and com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers to your Info.plist as needed.
reference : https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager

Permissions are already there, even I can use NFC on NFC enabled devices. I want to disable NFC for devices with hardware unavailibility.

Had to fork nfc_manager, and update platform specific code.
Added isEnabled & openSettings methods.
You can use: https://github.com/s4nk37/flutter-nfc-manager
until it gets merged.

For checking that NFC hardware is available, you need to code in Kotlin or java and use it in flutter with channel method.
an easy way to solve this problem without coding in Kotlin or java is using flutter_open_app_settings along with flutter_nfc_kit.
The flutter_nfc_kit will inform user that NFC is available or not.
if the NFC is not available you can show a dialog to user with a button and use flutter_open_app_settings to navigate user to NFC setting page in which user can enable NFC if it is supported.
The Flutter code for This solution:


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_nfc_kit/flutter_nfc_kit.dart' as nfc;
import 'package:flutter_open_app_settings/flutter_open_app_settings.dart'
    as settings;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Check NFC',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _nfcStatus = '';

  void _checkNfc() async {
    var availability = await nfc.FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
    if (availability != nfc.NFCAvailability.available) {
      _nfcStatus = 'Not available';
    } else {
      _nfcStatus = 'available';
    }
    setState(() {});
  }


  void _openNfcSettings() async {
    settings.FlutterOpenAppSettings.openAppsSettings(
      settingsCode: settings.SettingsCode.NFC,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Check NFC'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              _nfcStatus,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _openNfcSettings,
              child: const Text(
                'Open NFC settings',
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _checkNfc,
              child: const Text(
                'Check nfc availability',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Don't forget to insert this line in AndroidManifest.xml:
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

And my minSdkVersion in android > app > build.gradle is 28 and this code worked properly for me with this version.
